# How to force line breaks within a fancyvrb verbatim environment?

Tags: line-breaking, verbatim

Consider the following LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{example}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\}}
\begin{document}
\begin{example}
Foo\\{}Bar
Foo\linebreak{}Bar
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

I would expect the `\\` and `\linebreak` commands to produce a line break each, so the typeset output ought to look like

```
Foo
Bar
Foo
Bar
```

However, the actual output is

```
Foo               Bar
FooBar
```

How do I produce an explicit line break inside a fancyvrb-based verbatim environment?

(Incidentally »Just hit Return« isn't the answer I'm looking for. I have lots of text based on the alltt environment which contains markup like

```
Foo\nextline Bar
```

I use this to introduce »typographic« line breaks in shell command output, where there is no actual line break in the output but I need to start a new line because there is no more room on the current line. In my document, these »typographic« line breaks can be distinguished from genuine line breaks because there is a special symbol before/after the line break, along the lines of

```
\newcommand{\nextline}{\ensuremath{\rhd}\linebreak\ensuremath{\lhd}}
```

I'd much rather not change a couple thousand pages' worth of documentation.)

Comment: Would using `listings` instead of (or together with) `fancyvrb` be acceptable? If this is the caso, you van keep your current environment in the doucment body and simply define it differently in your preamble; something like `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{%
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  breaklines=true,
  columns=fullflexible,
  escapeinside = ||,
  breakindent=0pt,
}

\lstnewenvironment{example}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
Foo|\\|Bar
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}`

Comment: I'm afraid `fancyvrb` typesets each line in a `\hbox`. The `listings` package allows for line breaks and even provides hooks for symbols at end and start of broken lines.

Answer (score 5):

I am afraid `fancyvrb` doesn't allow what you want to do; a possible workaround would be using the [listings](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package instead of (or together with) `fancyvrb` (`listings` offers automatic line breaking and many other useful features; please refer to the package documentation for details). You can keep your current `example` environment in the document body, and simply define it using `listings` in your preamble; something like this:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{listings} 

\lstset{% 
  basicstyle=\ttfamily, 
  breaklines=true,
  columns=fullflexible,
  escapeinside = ||,
  breakindent=0pt} 
\lstnewenvironment{example}{}{} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{example} 
Foo|\\|Bar 
\end{example} 

\end{document}
```

[image]