# Partially expanding a command

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion

My `\john` command is defined like so:

```
\def\john{\DontExpandMe}
```

I would now like to repeatedly change its definition, to keep adding some extra stuff on the front.

```
\foreach\i in {ape,bat,cow,dog} {
  \xdef\john{\i,\unexpanded{\john}}
  \show\john
}
```

My intention is that the `\show\john` command at each iteration should result in:

```
\john=macro: -> \DontExpandMe.
\john=macro: -> ape,\DontExpandMe.
\john=macro: -> bat,ape,\DontExpandMe.
\john=macro: -> cow,bat,ape,\DontExpandMe.
\john=macro: -> dog,cow,bat,ape,\DontExpandMe.
```

That is to say, I would like `\john` to be "partially expanded" in some sense. But I can't make that work. I have tried the following

- If I use an `\xdef`, then the whole command is expanded, including the `\DontExpandMe` part.
- If I just use a `\gdef`, then the `\i` is not expanded.
- If I use `\xdef` with `\unexpanded{...}` around `\john` (as I have in my current code) then I get `\john=macro: -> ape,\john.` and `\john=macro: -> bat,\john.` and so on.

Here is my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
  \def\john{\DontExpandMe}
  \show\john
  \foreach\i in {ape,bat,cow,dog} {
    \xdef\john{\i,\unexpanded{\john}}
    \show\john
  }
\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe you want `etoolbox`'s `\expandonce` instead of `\unexpanded`

Comment: I have a feeling we've had this question before in some way!

Comment: Similar to (but distinct from) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115758/preserving-and-controlling-expandedness

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The line in question is:

```
\xdef\john{\i,\unexpanded{\john}}
```

`\i` should expanded (full/once?) and `\john` should be expanded once

### Partial expansion with `\xdef` and `\unexpanded`:

Before `\unexpanded` reads the open curly brace, it is in expanding mode
for gobbling spaces. Therefore it can be used to sneak in a `\expandafter`:

```
\xdef\john{\i,\unexpanded\expandafter{\john}}
```

(Without this trick, *two* `\expandafter` would be needed:

```
\xdef\john{\i,\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\john}}
```

The same can also be achieved without e-TeX by using a token register:

```
\toks0=\expandafter{\john}% similar trick as above to minimize the number of \expandafter
\xdef\john{\i,\the\toks0}
```

The contents of the token register is not further expanded inside `\edef`.

### One expansion step for `\i` and `\john`:

- Same as above, but for `\i`, too:

  ```
  \xdef\john{\unexpanded\expandafter{\i},\unexpanded\expandafter{\john}}
  ```
- `\expandafter` orgy with `\gdef`:

  ```
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\gdef
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\john
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\i\expandafter,\john
  }
  ```

  First `\john` is expanded once, then `\i`.

Comment: Thank you Heiko. (+1 for the `\expandafter` orgy!)

Answer (score 8):

There are many ways to do this; the easiest, but riskier, is to use `\xdef`:

```
\def\john{\DontExpandMe}
\show\john
\foreach\i in {ape,bat,cow,dog} {%
  \xdef\john{\i,\unexpanded\expandafter{\john}}%
  \show\john
}
```

Why riskier? Try with `\textbf{ape}` in the list to see the effect: commands that don't survive `\edef` will make the code die horribly. A better choice would be expanding also `\i` only once:

```
  \xdef\john{\unexpanded\expandafter{\i},\unexpanded\expandafter{\john}}%
```

Using token registers might be an option:

```
\def\john{\DontExpandMe}
\show\john
\foreach\i in {ape,bat,cow,dog} {%
  \toks0=\expandafter{\i}%
  \toks2=\expandafter{\john}%
  \xdef\john{\the\toks0,\the\toks2}%
  \show\john
}
```

Tokens delivered by `\the<token registers>` are not subject to further expansion in an `\edef` or `\xdef`.

A macro in LaTeX3 language:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\prependreverselist}{mm}
 {% #1 is the macro to extend; #2 is the list
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \tl_put_left:Nn #1 { ##1 , }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\john}{\DontExpandMe}

\prependreverselist{\john}{ape,bat,cow,dog}

\show\john
```

Comment: Cool, thanks `:-)`. Why do you use `\toks0` and `\toks2` rather than, say, `\toks0` and `\toks1`?

Comment: I'd use a group for the toks (see my answer, which I'll probably remove).

Comment: @JohnWickerson By convention, even-numbered scratch registers should be used locally and odd-numbered ones globally. So `\toks1` is not appropriate here.

Comment: @JosephWright `\foreach` does each cycle in a group, so adding one is not necessary.

Answer (score 6):

At the TeX level, this can be done at least couple ways depending on whether we assume e-TeX is available. The classical way, with no e-TeX, is to use a token register for the definition:

```
\long\def\addtoclist#1#2{%
  \begingroup
    \toks@\expandafter{#1}%
    \toks2{#2}%
    \edef#1{\the\toks2,\the\toks@}%
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1}%
}
```

where I've been cautious and assumed that the new material (`#2`) should not expand at all. The way that the above works is that TeX only expands token registers ('toks') once inside an `\edef`, so I can be sure no further expansion will occur. I've used two temporary toks: `\toks@` (which is `\toks0` addressed by name), and `\toks2` (addressed by number). The group means I won't affect any value already stored in these.

With e-TeX, we don't need the group or toks assignments

```
\protected\long\def\addtoclist#1#2{%
  \edef#1{\unexpanded{#2},\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}}%
}
```

where the `\unexpanded` primitive has behaviour similar to a toks: you can expand the material to be assigned using `\expandafter` just before the `{`.

(In both cases, you really need to check for an empty initial definition, but that is not the key point here.)

Answer (score 5):

With the help of **[cgnieder's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116823/partially-expanding-a-command/116825#comment259171_116823)**, I have fixed my code as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
  \def\john{\DontExpandMe}
  \show\john
  \foreach\i in {ape,bat,cow,dog} {
    \xdef\john{\i,\expandonce{\john}}
    \show\john
  }
\end{document}
```

And with the help of **[cgnieder's other comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116823/partially-expanding-a-command#comment259177_116825)**, I have shortened my code as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
  \def\john{\DontExpandMe}
  \show\john
  \foreach\i in {ape,bat,cow,dog} {
    \xdef\john{\i,\unexpanded\expandafter{\john}}
    \show\john
  }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually you don't need `etoolbox` for this. The definition of `\expandonce` is simple: `\newcommand{\expandonce}[1]{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}}`